# Mysql fulltext search with multiple fulltext indexes

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have this mysql table with these two fulltext indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl` ADD FULLTEXT `fulltext_idx` (`name`, `label`);
ALTER TABLE `tbl` ADD FULLTEXT `fulltext_idx2` (`keywords`, `title`);
```

How can I perform a fulltext search on table tbl by matching words from both indexes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For `FullText` Search to work your database `Table` engine must be `MyIsam`.

**Syntax**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
    WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('label') AND
     MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('title');
```

Comment: The InnoDB engine also supports Full Text search since mysql 5.6.4 (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html)

Comment: The InnoDB engine also supports Full Text search, HOWEVER, the MATCH() column list must match EXACTLY the column list in the FULLTEXT index definition for the table (not be a subset of columns). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: The above is just plain wrong. AGAINST is the text you're matching and MATCH must match the column list of one of the indexes

Answer (score 0):

I have an innodb and wanted something similar and I solved with inserting all of them in the same fulltext index:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl` ADD FULLTEXT `fulltext_idxAll` (`name`, `label`,`keywords`,`title`);
```

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MATCH (`name`, `label`,`keywords`,`title`) AGAINST ('whatever')
```

my query was a little bit more complex but this should work, let me know if it suits you.